# Access an SSL protected server using https?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ssl, https

I am client side developer (Unity/C#) and I have API that require SSL certificate at connection. I have this certificate (.pfx).
When I try to make request by HttpWebRequest class (code listen below) I have error (code 400: Bad request, No required SSL certificate was sent). Any idea how to make it works?

When I put my URL in browser I have popup which asks for certificate and I can provide certificate there and then I have result!

Maybe I need to use Stream from request?

Here is how request looks in Inspector:
[image]

```
void Connect() {
    // I think it is not necessary
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);

    // certificate creation
    certificate = new X509Certificate2(path, pass); 

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    // adding certificate to request
    request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.AuthenticationLevel = AuthenticationLevel.MutualAuthRequested;
    request.Accept = "application/json";

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}

public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(
        object sender,
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate,
        X509Chain chain,
        System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
}
```